# WebView doesn't change height when trying to resize font in ScrollView

Tags: android, webview, height, android-webview, scrollview

I searched for hours on the internet to find a solution (see title) and there is still no solid fix. The only way to solve the problem is to replace the current WebView with a new one. Till now, replacing works fine, but I need a real solution for in the future. Way to go Google for still not fixing this issue.

Is there anyone that came with a solid fix? I think that Google needs to rebuild the whole WebView and add more features so that we can get the WebView content height, etc, etc...

Keep in mind that I found many old solutions that still don't work or support a few devices.

Here is my code:

```
/**
* ON FONT UP CLICKED
*/
@OnClick( R.id.bottomBar_fontUpIV ) void onFontUpClicked() {
    appHelper.saveFontSize( String.valueOf( appHelper.getFontSize() + 1 ) );
    reloadWebViews();
}


/**
* ON FONT DOWN CLICKED
*/
@OnClick( R.id.bottomBar_fontDownIV ) void onFontDownClicked() {
    appHelper.saveFontSize( String.valueOf( appHelper.getFontSize() - 1 ) );
    reloadWebViews();
}

/**
* ON RELOAD WEB VIEW
*/
public void reloadWebViews() {

    scrollChild.removeView( titleTextWV );
    scrollChild.removeView( mainTextWV );

    viewDetails();

}

/**
 * VIEW DETAILS
 */
public void viewDetails() {

    dateText.setText( appHelper.getConvertedDate( model.getDateTime(), true ) );
    dateText.setTextSize( appHelper.getFontSize() );

    if( model.getIntroText() != null ) {
        titleTextWV = setDefaultWebViewSettings( "<b>" + model.getIntroText() + "</b>" );
        scrollChild.addView(titleTextWV);
    }

    mainTextWV = setDefaultWebViewSettings( model.getMainText() );
    scrollChild.addView( mainTextWV );
}
```

Comment: what version are you testing on? I presume this is a height=wrap_content WebView, right?

Comment: Which version of Android?

Comment: There was a bug where the WebView would not shrink up till JB but I guess that's not it. Does this work correctly if the WebView is not in a ScrollView? To take this any further I'd need a solid repro, do you have an .apk where this is happening?

Comment: Please review my code. Thank you for the help. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68471/discussion-between-marcin-kosiba-and-xarialon).